# Direct sum in free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

I am doing an exercise from "an introduction to homological algebra by Charles A.Weibel" and I am not able to get it, but if the following comes true then I think I can solve the exercise, but I don't know whether the following is true or not.

Let $M$ and $N$ are free $R$-modules. Let $L$ be an $R$-module such that $M \cong L \oplus N$. Does it implies that $L$ is a free $R$-module.

Please help me.

Comment: Equivalently, you could ask if $M/N$ is free.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: I got your point, but I am not able to figure out how this would help?

Comment: Quotient of two free modules?

Comment: @Wuestenfux: If M is of finite rank, then I can prove that L is free R module from the hint given by you,  but when M is not of finite rank, how should I proceed?

Comment: @Sneh you cannot proceed. The statement is not true: direct summands of a free module need not be free.

Comment: @Wuestenfux This is not equivalent. Direct summand is not just any quotient. And it is very easy to construct a quotient of free modules that is not free, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @freakish: Thank you. I got your point. I was thinking of M and N as direct sum of copies of R and then mod out. I was wrong.